# Iterating over children of a particular tag using elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am a beginner to [elementtree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) concepts.

I just learnt how to iterate over all the tags in xml file.

```
for elem in root.iter():
    print elem.tag, elem.attrib
```

Now, I want to iterate over all the children of a particular tag.

Let's name the tag as `"teams"`.

So, I want to iterate over all the children of this tag.

How can I achieve this? I am using python for parsing the xml file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [simple XPath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) selector expression to get all child elements of `teams` :

```
for elem in root.findall(".//teams/*"):
    print elem.tag, elem.attrib
```

Comment: So simple when you know it ! Thanks @har07

Answer (score 2):

Let assume You have file:

**example.xml:**

```
<example>
    <sample>
        <teams>
            <team>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>example1</name>
            </team>
            <team>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>example2</name>
            </team>
            <team>
                <id>3</id>
                <name>example3</name>
            </team>
        </teams>
    </sample>
    <league>
        <amateur>
            <teams>
                <team>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <name>example1</name>
                </team>
                <team>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <name>example2</name>
                </team>
                <team>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <name>example3</name>
                </team>
            </teams>
        </amateur>
        <pro>
            <teams>
                <team>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <name>example1</name>
                </team>
                <team>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <name>example2</name>
                </team>
                <team>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <name>example3</name>
                </team>
            </teams>
        </pro>
    </league>
</example>
```

## Minidom:

Now using Python You can do this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
exampleDOM = minidom.parse('example.xml')
teams = exampleDOM.getElementsByTagName('teams')[0] # in sample section
for team in teams.getElementsByTagName('team'):
    id = team.getElementsByTagName('id')[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
    name = team.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
    print('Team (%s): %s' % (id, name))
```

**Output:**

```
Team (1): example1
Team (2): example2
Team (3): example3
```

## ElementTree

Using `ElementTree` library You can achieve this easier:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for teams in root.iter('teams'):
    for team in teams.iter('team'):
         id = team.find('id').text
         name = team.find('name').text
         print('Team (%s): %s' % (id, name))
```

**Output:**

```
Team (1): example1
Team (2): example2
Team (3): example3
Team (1): example1
Team (2): example2
Team (3): example3
Team (1): example1
Team (2): example2
Team (3): example3
```

Comment: @shivammitra I've added example for `ElementTree` lib

Comment: Sorry for the comment after suck a long time, but I have a question: why with `ElementTree` you are performing two nested loops, and not writing `for team in root.iter('team'):`? Is there some difference?

Comment: This is very good comment and for given example works perfectly but for more generic solution is to broad, like catching Exception class not only specific. In XML you can have `team` tag not related with `teams` and it will be processed.